# Myloader error during Restorin MariadDB Slave: Duplicate entry 'ТОБАР' for key 'UX_B_SEARCH_STEM'

Tags: replication, mariadb, master-slave

I have lost my slave. To restore it I have locked tables on the master host and then have created a dump using mydumper tool. After that I have tried to restore my slave using myloader tool but during the restoration process I´ve got one critical error:

```
** (myloader:190XXXX): WARNING **: 18:28:15.810: Thread 1: Error restoring 1: Duplicate entry 'ТОБXX' for key 'UX_B_SEARCH_STEM'

** (myloader:190XXXX): WARNING **: 18:28:15.810: Thread 1: Retrying last failed executed statement
** Message: 18:28:15.958: Thread 3: restoring `egats_tixmi`.`b_search_stem` part 1 of 1 from egats_tixmi.b_search_stem.00000.sql. Progress 113 of 488. Tables 0 of 1263 completed

** (myloader:190XXXX): CRITICAL **: 18:28:19.072: Thread 1: Error restoring: Duplicate entry 'ТОБXX' for key 'UX_B_SEARCH_STEM'

** (myloader:190XXXX): CRITICAL **: 18:28:19.072: Error occurs between lines: 4 and 7798 on file tixmi.b_search_stem.00000.sql: Duplicate entry 'ТОБXX' for key 'UX_B_SEARCH_STEM'

** (myloader:190XXXX): CRITICAL **: 18:28:18.070: Thread 1: issue restoring tixmi.b_search_stem.00000.sql:
```

How critical is that? Right now my slave working without any issues but looks like the data identity between master and slave couldn't be 100% guaranteed. What would be the best strategy to be sure that all is good without repeating the whole restoration process?

Answer (score 0):

A previous (now fixed bug) [MDEV-31120](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31120) may have affected your backups.

I recommend restoring to a version equal or later than the fixVersion in bug report (10.6.15, 10.9.8, 10.10.6, 10.11.5).

You might have duplicates in your master. If you had a mydumper with '--insert-ignore' or using `sed` changed `INSERT` to `INSERT IGNORE`.

This is however leaving it to chance as to which entry is duplicate.

I recommend:

1. getting the replica to a newer version than the above
2. `set global unique_checks=0`
3. restoring the data with myloader
4. identifying a strategy resolve the duplicate entries (removing oldest, merging), something. depends on data without applying it on the replica.
5. if the master isn't of a sufficiently new version update it.
6. start replication
7. apply the duplicate removing strategy on the master
8. after replication caught up, `set global unique_checks=1` on replica.

Confirmation/sanity check of this by another person much appreciated.